# react autocomplete dropdown position pushing down other inputs elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, autocomplete

I have autocomplete dropdown , i have followed this [link](https://www.positronx.io/react-autocomplete-tutorial-with-example/). I am facing issue in terms of displaying drop down items.

as i shown in the link, the drop down items are displayed in `div` tag with `poistion` as `relative`

css

```css
.autocomplete-wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  display:  inline-block;
}

.autocomplete-wrapper > div {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.autocomplete-wrapper input {
  border: 1px solid #cecece;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 100%;
}

.autocomplete-wrapper input:focus {
  border-color: #0F67FF;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
}

.autocomplete-wrapper Autocomplete{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

.autocomplete-wrapper .dropdown {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
  max-height: 280px;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #0F67FF;
  border-top: none;
  z-index: 2;
}

.autocomplete-wrapper .item  {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.autocomplete-wrapper .item.selected-item {
  background-color: #0069ff;
  color: #FAFBFC;
}

.autocomplete-wrapper .item:hover {
  background-color: #0069ff;
  color: #FAFBFC;
}
```

i tried giving `position` as `absolute` but it is overlapping with other input elements. i want the poistion of drop down should not disturb other input elements, like traditional react select dropdown.

code

> ```
>        <div className="autocomplete-wrapper">
>         <label htmlFor="title">Vehilce No</label>
>         <Autocomplete 
>           value={state.val}
>           items={vehicles}
>           getItemValue={item => item.numberPlate}
>           shouldItemRender={renderVehicleNumber}
>           renderMenu={item => (
>             <div className="dropdown">
>               {item}
>             </div>
>           )}
>           renderItem={(item, isHighlighted) =>
>             <div className={`item ${isHighlighted ? 'selected-item' : ''}`}>
>               {item.numberPlate}
>             </div>
>           }
>           onChange={(event, val) => setState({ val })}
>           onSelect={val => setState({ val })}
>         />
>       </div>
>     </div>
>     <div className="form-group">
>     <label htmlFor="price"> </label>
>     <span>   </span>
>
>     </div>
>     <div className="form-group" style={{position: "static"}}> 
>       <label htmlFor="price">Price</label>
>       <input
>         type="number"
>         className="form-control"
>         id="price"
>         required
>         value={creditEntry.price}
>         onChange={handleInputChange}
>         name="price"
>       />
>     </div>
>     <div className="form-group">
>       <label htmlFor="price">Litre</label>
>       <input
>         type="number"
>         className="form-control"
>         id="price"
>         required
>         value={creditEntry.litre}
>         onChange={handleInputChange}
>         name="price"
>       />
>     </div>
> ```

[image: dropdown position issue.]

Comment: Can you post more code please? For example what are the parent elements around this auto-complete, and the elements that the auto-complete is disturbing.

Answer (score 0):

I've added

```
z-index: 500;
position: fixed;
```

to the wrapper style `.autocomplete-wrapper .dropdown {...`. It now looks like this

```
.autocomplete-wrapper .dropdown {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
  max-height: 280px;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #0F67FF;
  border-top: none;
  z-index: 500;
  position: fixed;
}
```

Both `z-index: 500;` and `position: fixed;` are essential to make it work.